# VPN Virtual Appliance Recommendation Sought: 2 factor and other reqs below

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, active-directory

We are looking to deploy a VPN server endpoint and are looking for suggestions of a known solid solution.

Needed features:

- Good client app for Win and OSX
- Solid 2 factor auth built in, with option to use google authenticator
- Management UI that lets us set up, user by user, what host:port they can access
- Integration with Active Directory for initial auth (then followed by 2nd factor that is specific to VPN connection, 2nd factor not part of AD)

We tried the dell sonicwall Secure Remote Appliance, which is overall nice, but it lacks good 2 factor support

We are now considering the [barracuda virtual appliance](https://www.barracuda.com/products/sslvpnvx)

What does the community suggest?